# Hive: struct as a key in map type when creating table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm trying to create a table in Hive created from a spark job with the following data format:

```
{'Group1': {[start=0, end=20]: 'Data goes here'}}
```

The spark dataframe schema for this is:

```
MapType(StringType(),
        MapType(StructType([
                StructField('start', IntegerType(), False),
                StructField('end', IntegerType(), False)]),
                StringType()))
```

which displays as:

```
root
 |-- column_1: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: struct
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- start: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- end: integer (nullable = true)
```

This seems to work just fine in spark but when I try to create a hive table from this schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table (
column_1 MAP<STRING, MAP<STRUCT<`start`:BIGINT,`end`:BIGINT>, STRING>>
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'path_to_files';
```

I get:

```
FAILED: ParseException cannot recognize input near 'STRUCT' '<' 'start' in primitive type specification
```

It looks like legal table construction as far as I can tell. I can't find anything that tells me you can't have `struct` as a key in a `map` with hive 2.0 and spark 2.0 handles it just fine.

Comment: What is your use case ? why are you trying to create hive table using hive command ?

Comment: spark dataframe can be created two ways , 1) From data sources directly 2) From existing RDD

Comment: Use case is creating a table in hive to be queried via a prestoDB cluster. The mention of spark was simply to indicate that the construction seems legal and to give people an idea of how the schema came to be.

Comment: remove single quotes/backticks for start and end and try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hive the key for a Map column must be a primitive (i.e. not a Struct).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-ComplexTypes

I would highly recommend you not make the key a Struct.  In your example, how do I access the value of the Map if I don't know the start or end?  The user would need to know the exact start and end and does it change for each row in your table?

Comment: Interestingly, if I create a table in Spark with a map column which has struct<> for key, Hive is able to happily query it and produce output (in a better format that Presto or Spark).

But they have not provided an option to create a table with a map column using struct key! Sad...